# Can not apply absolute position to react-colorful component?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS and ReactJS to build my project. And I have this code that have a react-colorful component. I want to apply 'absolute' position to it but it does not work.

**I have tried this code:**

```js
    <div className="w-full p-4 rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-white flex flex-col">
      <span className="mb-4 text-xl font-semibold">Branding</span>
      <div className="flex flex-col mb-1">
        <span className="font-medium">Brand color</span>
        <span className="text-sm text-gray-600">
          Used for backgrounds, borders etc.
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="relative w-1/2">
        <input
          ref={inputColorRef}
          placeholder="Color"
          defaultValue={defaultColor}
          onChange={handInputColorChange}
          className="px-2 py-1.5 w-full rounded-md ring-1 ring-gray-300 placeholder-gray-600 focus:ring-2 hover:ring-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-600 pl-10"
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => setColorPicker(!colorPicker)}
          style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
          className={`absolute h-8 left-0.5 top-0.5 w-8 rounded-md cursor-pointer`}
        ></button>
        {colorPicker && (
          <HexColorPicker
            color={color}
            onChange={handleColorChange}
            className="absolute top-1"
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>;
```

[image: Here is the image]

Any ideas or solutions to solve this. Thanks.